# Twilio Autopilot crashing when I use SSML?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, ssml

I'm making a twilio autopilot project and I want to use SSML for the responses. Every time I trigger the intent that contains SSML, it crashes without anything showing up in the debugger. Here's what I'm doing:

```
{
"actions": [
    {
        "say":"<speak>Hi, how can I help you today?</speak>"
    },
    {
        "listen": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Please note (if this matters) that I'm using the console for my project.

What am I doing wrong? Is this not how you use SSML for autopilot? I'm not redirecting this to another function or anything fancy.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

According to the [Voice TwiML docs for SSML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#ssml) (separate from the Autopilot docs at the moment), *when you’re using SSML with `<Say>` you can skip `<speak>` and insert rest of the SSML inside `<Say>`.*

You could adjust the prosody of the text that is said in a phone call using SSML in your JSON file like this:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "say": "<prosody rate='fast'>Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML) is a W3C specification that allows developers to use XML-based markup language for assisting the generation of synthesized speech.</prosody>"
        },
        {
            "listen": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps!